# SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain when using service account

Tags: git, ssl, self-signed-certificate

I'm developing a task/batch of Windows task scheduler that will clone repositories from our TFS git.
I ran into self-signed certificate problem

> fatal: unable to access 'https://repoName/': SSL certificate problem:
> self signed certificate in certificate chain

Which happens before. To deal with this, we will download/copy the certificate from the TFS site and add it into *ca-bundle.crt*. And run `git config --global http.sslCAInfo C:/Users/<UserName>/ca-bundle.crt`

The problem is after I applied solution above, if I run the task with my domain user account the task will work but if I run the task with a domain service account, I will still run into the same error.

Not sure what I need to do further to let the service account work.

I don't want to disable SSL verification.

Answer (score 0):

So ChatGPT helps me to figure out what went wrong.
It suggests running `git config --list --show-origin` to see if sslCAInfo is reference to the right file which it did not. It still references the default one.

I guess since when I ran `git config --global http.sslCAInfo C:/Users/<UserName>/ca-bundle.crt` it creates a reference specific to user instead of making it the *global* I thought.

Therefore, I use `PsExec.exe -u domain\account -p <password> cmd.exe` to open a cmd and run `git config --global http.sslCAInfo C:/Users/<UserName>/ca-bundle.crt` from there again.